# Unique User ID with Java

Tags: java

How can I generate alphanumeric unique userId's of 5/6 digits reducing the chances of collision upto 10 lac values with Java? I don't want to make calls every time  to the DB so as to check whether that ID already exists there.

Comment: If you want them to be persistent (i.e. survive after app restart) you need to use an external source or rely on something like SecureRandom.

Comment: another alternative (inspired by one of the answers below) is to use a unique information that is coming from users (like email) and hash it

Comment: I want  to use these as userId's to login into an app. As per you the Secure Random thing will be suitable for me. If you can provide a link from where I can know more about this.

Comment: You can have your database [generate it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Alternatively see[UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

Comment: What is “lac values”?

Comment: 5-6 digits or characters is not likely enough entropy to avoid collisions. If you want universally unique identifiers, use, well, [*Universally Unique Identifiers* (UUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). These are [128-bit values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/128-bit). Some databases offer native support for such values. UUIDs are often displayed textually as a 36-character hex string with hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

If your users do not supply any additional information (e.g. real name, email address, ...) you will have to try your luck with a purely random string as user name. One option to generate random strings is the [RandomStringGenerator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.Builder.html) of [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/userguide.html).

```java
import org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator;

...

RandomStringGenerator randomStringGenerator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
    .filteredBy(c -> Character.isLetterOrDigit(c) && c <= 122)
    .build();
String username = RandomStringGenerator.generate(6)
```

This code will produce user names like

```
3gmNQJ
Hz4DXy
c6X99p
FZJ5jQ
twKgZG
7ukgAY
Lq9qgB
...
```

However, your actual logic should be prepared to handle collisions between user names. A 6 character long random string is not too safe not to generate any collisions on the long run.

A safer alternative are [UUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions), but they are much longer and not very user friendly if someone has to enter them during a login process.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an hash code of the entire entity.
Basing on the hashing algorithm you choose (e.g. SHA1) the collisions are very rare.